# Mac always defaults to printing in B&W on HP OfficeJet L7650

Tags: macos, mac, printer, macbook

I have several Macs on my network.  One, a very new MBP, always defaults to printing in B&W on my OfficeJet L7650.  In any program's print dialog, I can navigate to Paper Type/Quality -> Color Options and manually change from Grayscale to ColorSmart/sRGB, but the change is not permanent. My other Macs on the same network running same version of SL with the same up to date HP drivers don't have this issue. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an exchange with HP tech support, the solution is to make the change to ColorSmart/sRGB and then save the Standard print setup.